# How can I export a Binary PFX from CertEnroll?

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates, certenroll

I'm having trouble with `objEnroll.CreatePFX` where the only return type is string, and what I need is a binary output comparable to what happens when I open the Certificates MMC and export a PFX.

This is important because I need the original PFX format so I can import the private key into OSX and iPhone.

```
    CX509Enrollment objEnroll = new CX509Enrollment();
   objEnroll.InitializeFromTemplateName(
                X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser,
                templateName);
   // ...
   objEnroll.Enroll();
   string pfxString = objEnroll.CreatePFX("q", PFXExportOptions.PFXExportEEOnly, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BINARY);
```

What is the correct way to set the `EncodingType` so that it can be properly converted into a binary output? (Similar to a Windows certificate export )

Answer (score 3):

Just write the base64 string into a file

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("MyFile.pfx", pfxString);
```

Windows will handle the PFX.

You can also convert base64 to binary using

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("MyFile.pfx", System.Convert.FromBase64String(pfxString));
```